# Python dictionary unpacking

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
def fun(a, b, c): 
    print(a, b, c) 

d = {'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':10} 
fun(**d)
```

This code prints `2, 4, 10`. I would like to know why only dictionary values got printed and not the keys.

Comment: Because with the unpacking operator `**` you assign the parameter `a` to the _value_ of _key_ `'a'`, etc.

Comment: The values get bound by name to their keys. `fun(**d)` is equivalent to calling `fun(a=2, b=4, c=10)`

Comment: In what variable exactly would you expect the key names to be transported?

Answer (score -1):

use * for Keys and ** for Values as below

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To pass a dictionary in a function or method argument you use **kwargs

```
def fun(**kwargs):
    print kwargs     #<-- this prints the dictionary with it's keys

d = {'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':10} 
fun(**d)
```